# Write the closed interval $[a,b]$ as the union of semi-intervals.

Tags: real-analysis

Write the closed interval $[a,b]$ as the union of semi-intervals.

Attempt:

$$[a,b] = \bigcup_n^\infty\ \left[a,b-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: Does $b$ belong to  $\bigcup_n^\infty [a,b-\frac{1}{n})$ ?

Comment: No, that union is $[a,b)$. If the definition of "semi-interval" is $[x,y)$, then $[a,b]$ is _not_ a union of semi-intervals. Is that really what the problem asked? Or did it really say do this or show it can't be done, or what? (Or do $[x,y)$ and $(x,y]$ both count as semi-intervals?)

Answer (score 6):

Is it not as simple as $$[a,b]=[a,b)\cup(a,b]$$